# Java Bukkit API - Get LastDamageCause Entity in PlayerMoveMent Event

Tags: java, bukkit

So I am trying to figure out how to get the last damage cause when a **player** reaches the *void* in minecraft. However, I cannot find a way how to get the **damager**.

So here is my event handler

```
@EventHandler
public void on(PlayerMoveEvent event)
{
    Player player = (Player)event.getPlayer();

    if (event.getTo().getY() <= 20.0)
    {
        Entity damager = (Player) event.getPlayer().getLastDamageCause().getEntity();

        if(damager instanceof Player)
        {
            if(player.getLastDamageCause().getEntity().equals(damager))
            {
                damager.sendMessage("KILLER WORKING");
                player.sendMessage("WOKRING!!!!");  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Somehow when I got damaged (player), it gives both messages. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You recieve both messages since both the player and damager are the same at that time.

You get the entity from `getLastDamageCause().getEntity()`, store it into the damager object. Then check if the damager is equals to the `getLastDamageCause().getEntity()`, which always will returns true.

To solve your problem, according to this [topic](https://bukkit.org/threads/player-getlastdamagecause-getentity-returning-the-player.283177/) *"getEntity() returns the subject of the DamageEvent, not the damager. To get the damager, you need to check:"*

```
if(player.getLastDamageCause() instanceof EntityDamageByEntityEvent)
    Player damager = ((EntityDamageByEntityEvent) player.getLastDamageCause()).getDamager();
```

That code returns the player who damages a player, for an entity I do not know. But it seems you only need to check it if it's a player anyway.

By the way there is no need to cast `event.getPlayer()` into a player, since it's already a player.

Comment: Thank you very much, its works now!! You safed my life :D